# tsql breaking a comma seperated string and then looping

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

i have comma seperated string

```
a=1,2,3,4
```

now i want to break this string and then loop through it using 1,2,3 etc in the query in tsql in sql server 2008

```
set @sql = @sql + ' and  (ClassicStation.int_WheatherTypeId = a[i]) AND (ClassicStation.int_MeasurementId IN (1,2)) or'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe fn_split is an option check http://odetocode.com/code/365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looks to me like you can just do this:

```
set @sql = @sql + 'and  (ClassicStation.int_WheatherTypeId in ('+@a+')) 
AND (ClassicStation.int_MeasurementId IN (1,2))'
```

Otherwise you can split the string with the split function that is located everywhere or
like this

```
declare @a varchar(max)
set @a ='1,2,3,4' + ','

;with csv (col, pos) as
(
select left(@a, charindex(',', @a) -1),charindex(',', @a)
union all
select substring(@a, pos +1, charindex(',', @a, pos +1) - pos-1), 
charindex(',',@a, pos+1) from csv
where pos < len(@a)
)
select * from csv
```